# Invoking java functions from RASCAL

Tags: rascal

can I invoke Java functions from Rascal. I want to write RASCAL analyser, but want access CFG nodes by calling a java function. Is this possible in Rascal. To put it simply, can I wrap the existing java application and invoke it from RASCAL

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it is satisfactory?

Comment: Are there any new libraries developed to support this? Is pdb.values be replaced by valLang library now?

Comment: yes, pdb.values was renamed to vallang. Otherwise there is no new API for the interpreter. For compiled Rascal programs the RVM.asInterface() method was added, which exposes a Rascal module to its Java counterpart as a POJO (with vallang interfaces to the parameters).

Answer (score 4):

Sure. It works as follows.

1. Treat your Rascal project in Eclipse as a Java project as well.
2. Add source code and libraries and make the stuff compile.
3. Learn about the pdb.values API (in particular `IValueFactory`)
4. In Rascal write something like this:

```
    @javaClass{com.mypackage.MyClass}
    java int myFunction(str arg);
```

1. Then in Java:

```
     package com.mypackage;    
     public class MyClass {
        private final IValueFactor vf;
        public MyClass(IValueFactory vf) { 
          this.vf = vf;
        }
        IValue myFunction(IString x) {
           return vf.integer(-1);
        }
     }
```